# Wellington, NZ cheap camping ground within 30mins bicycle from city

Tags: budget, camping, bicycles, new-zealand, wellington

I would like to do some bicycle camping within quick reach of the city.

Are there are any cheap or free sites that offer toilets? Showers not necessary, but would be luxury.

Comment: See also, perhaps, [Outdoors.SE].

Comment: Thanks @gerrit, seems there is an awesome site for everything!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wellington is actually a very small city geographically surrounded by large hills with several commuter towns that make up greater Wellington, such as Lower Hut, Upper Hut, and Porirua. When using Google maps in the area i suggest using the terrain function.

Wellington, It's technically Lower Hutt  [Top Ten Holiday Park](http://www.top10.co.nz/parks/wellington/) which is 15km (Google says 57 min on a bike) away from Te Papa (National Museum) which is on the waterfront in downtown wellington. .

[Camp Elsdon](http://www.campelsdon.co.nz/conditions.html) in Porirua which is 21km (Google say 1 hour 35 min on a bike) away from Te Papa.

Wellington, it's technically in Upper Hutt [Kiwi Holiday Park](http://www.harcourtholidaypark.co.nz/) which is 40.6 km (Google says 2 hours 22 mins) away from Te Papa.